# Send BCC with PHP mail()

Tags: php, phpmailer, bcc

This is my code:

```
<?php
$to = "you@example.com";
$subject = "This is the subject!";
$message = "This is the message!";
$headers = 'From: Me<me@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: me@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting the Bcc email. Why that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `BCC` should be part of the header, not a different parameter. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php. Specifically `$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";`.

Comment: Look [at the flippin manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) there is a perfectly good example in there

Comment: Hey @chris85, did you mean like that?
`$to = "you@example.com";`
`$subject = "This is the subject!";`
`$message = "This is the message!";`
`$headers .= 'From: Me<me@example.com>' . "\r\n";`
$headers .= 'Bcc: me@example.com' . "\r\n";
`mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);`

Comment: Yea, something like that, is that from the manual? You can edit the question, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40205117/edit and add an update if you are having different issues.

Comment: @chris85, I updated my question. Can you help me?